# Oracle 11G - Determining Peak Processes and Sessions

Tags: oracle, session, process, oracle11g

So as part of the reconfiguration of our oracle database I am trying to figure out what is the peak amount of processes from an instance of our database.

Whilst I am able to obtain the current processes/sessions which are running on the database I am unsure of if there is a function/view which contains this information in 11G.

I've done a search however nothing has really come up.

Thanks,
C

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understand correctly that you want to find historic data on session activity in order to monitor performance. There are several solutions I can think of.

I'd suggest DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY, V$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY for historical data and V$SESSION for current data. (I guess you are using V$SESSION to get the current processes/sessions status).

If that is not sufficient you can always create your own procedure with scheduled execution and store snapshots of current status somewhere or use Zabbix trapper (or any other monitoring tool of you choice) to monitor DB activity.

If you have Oracle Enterprise Manager I'd recommend using that. You can use performance page there to see both current and historic data on sessions and also generate ASH reports.

Answer (score 0):

Peak processes and sessions are available in the Active Workload Repository (AWR) in `DBA_HIST_SYSMETRIC_SUMMARY`.

```
--Maximum number of sessions.
select instance_number, maxval, begin_time
from dba_hist_sysmetric_summary
where metric_name = 'Session Count'
order by maxval desc, begin_time desc;

--Maximum number of processes.
--This is a little trickier because only the Limit is stored so it must be compared
--to the parameter value.
--This assumes that the PROCESSES parameter hasn't changed recently.
select instance_number, round(maxval/100 * gv$parameter.value) processes, begin_time
from dba_hist_sysmetric_summary
join gv$parameter
    on dba_hist_sysmetric_summary.instance_number = gv$parameter.inst_id
where gv$parameter.name = 'processes'
    and metric_name = 'Process Limit %'
order by processes desc, begin_time desc;
```

That's probably enough information to set the PROCESSES and SESSIONS parameters.  If what you really need is to know how *active* the database was, then looking at
 `DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY`, like J91321 mentioned, is probably a better method.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys, can you think of a reason why these tables/views are not present within my DB?

As it's throwing me the error "ORA-00942 table or view does not exist". I am not the DBA for the database but I do have access to it to make the occasional query whenever it is asked of me.

Comment: @varilight You probably don't have permission to see that table.  You'll need either the role `SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE` or the system privilege `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY`.

Comment: Well I think to access any view starting with DBA prefix you either need DBA role or specific privilege for that view. Contact your DBA.